# Posting Twice to MySQL But Only On Occasion? Seconds Between Each Posting

Tags: php, html

I have a script that posts form data to MySQL Database (see code below). However, this is on occasion posting twice. If I look at the times, there is typically about a second between each posting.

If I used INSERT IGNORE would this prevent this from happening? It literally only happens once in every 15 to 25 form submits and I can't workout a pattern.

If I used INSERT IGNORE would that still send the email twice or would that end the script at that point?

```
<?php

session_start();

$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

$path .= "/conn.php";

require_once($path);

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Medical (Full_Name, Team, Activity, Reason, Region, Description, Treatment) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $name, $team, $activity, $reason, $region, $description, $treatment);

    $name = $_POST['name'];

    $team = $_POST['team'];

    $activity = $_POST['activity'];

    $reason = $_POST['reason'];

    $region = $_POST['region'];

    $description = $_POST['description'];

    $treatment = $_POST['treatment'];

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->close();

    $to = "EMAIL HIDDEN";

    $subject = "New Injury Reported";

    $headers = "From: EMAIL HIDDEN";

    $message = $name . " Reported a New Injury via the App.";

    $sent = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    $_SESSION['Alert-Type'] = 'success';

    $_SESSION['Alert-Head'] = "Success";

    $_SESSION['Alert-Text'] = "Thank You <strong>" . $name . "</strong> Your Injury Has Been Reported To Sports Science.";

    header("location: index.php");
}

?>
```

Comment: This script does not insert anything twice. The problem is where you call this file - you probably call it multiple times.

Comment: Its just from a form <form action="handle.php" method="post">. I'd have thought if that was the issue it would happen every time? Not once every 25 posts or so. Would the "INSERT IGNORE" protect against this?

Comment: I just did a search on file for word 'handle.php' and it only comes back with 1 single match. Is anything I can do to stop it running twice?